# Mdn docs performance.timing returns epoch time, but is depreciated. Mdn docs recommends PerformanceResourceTiming for use but returns relative time

Tags: javascript, performance, mozilla, google-developers-console, resource-timing-api

I am trying to retrieve the epoch time for when a request is made to a server `requestStart` from the Mdn docs. I could've easily done this with `window.performance.timing` ; however, `timing` is now depreciated shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/timing).

This is the target data shown in epoch time using the depreciated `performance.timing` :

```
connectEnd: 1681158191016
connectStart: 1681158190760
domComplete: 1681158198077
domContentLoadedEventEnd: 1681158197612
domContentLoadedEventStart: 1681158197596
domInteractive: 1681158197596
domLoading: 1681158192909
domainLookupEnd: 1681158190760
domainLookupStart: 1681158190760
fetchStart: 1681158190644
loadEventEnd: 1681158198078
loadEventStart: 1681158198078
navigationStart: 1681158190622
redirectEnd: 0
redirectStart: 0
requestStart: 1681158191016 // needed value correct format
responseEnd: 1681158192980
responseStart: 1681158192893
secureConnectionStart: 1681158190836
unloadEventEnd: 1681158192902
unloadEventStart: 1681158192902
```

And when I use the interface that it recommended `PerformanceNavigationTiming` using the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming)

```
window.performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0]
```

I get the following response:

```
...
duration: 7455.199999988079
encodedBodySize: 22998
entryType: "navigation"
fetchStart: 21.19999998807907
initiatorType: "navigation"
loadEventEnd: 7455.199999988079
loadEventStart: 7454.900000035763
name: ""
nextHopProtocol: ""
redirectCount: 0
redirectEnd: 0
redirectStart: 0
renderBlockingStatus: "non-blocking"
requestStart: 393.30000001192093 // needed value incorrect format
responseEnd: 2357.900000035763
responseStart: 2270.199999988079
...
```

So I was just wondering how can I get the window performance to return epoch timing for the `PerformanceNavigationTiming` interface? Thanks

I tried `window.performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0]` and got the wrong time stamps that were relative